# Android: How to use a for loop to find the text value of several textViews?

Tags: android

I'm having trouble going from finding each view based on its actual id like this-

```
TextView updateText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.courtText1);
```

to finding each view based on the current value of "i" in my loop, like this-

```
for(int i=1; i<3; i++){
    TextView updateText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.courtText"i");
}
```

Here is the layout XML-

```
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/row_background"
                android:clipToPadding="true"
                android:padding="5dp" android:onClick="goToDetail">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/courtText1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Moscone Rec Center"
                        android:textColor="#D8D8D8"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/updateText1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#D8D8D8"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/timeText1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#D8D8D8"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" android:onClick="goToMap"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" android:onClick="shareUpdate"/>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/row_background"
                android:clipToPadding="true"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/courtText2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Joe Dimaggio"
                        android:textColor="#D8D8D8"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/updateText2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#D8D8D8"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/timeText2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#D8D8D8"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/row_background"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/courtText3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Brentwood Rec Center"
                        android:textColor="#D8D8D8"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/updateText3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#D8D8D8"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/timeText3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#D8D8D8"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/row_background"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Can't find your court?"
                        android:textColor="#D8D8D8"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />
                     <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Let us know"
                        android:textColor="#D8D8D8"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                     <ImageButton
                         android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" android:onClick="createSupportEmail"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

Any thoughts on how to find the value of each item with a loop?

Comment: I don't think you should use multiple views with the same ID. Also I think you should use more descriptive IDs. If you have so many views that you can't use descriptive IDs you should be asking yourself if using an adapter and a data source would be a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your container (`LinearLayout`) an id, and iterate over its children.

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.whatever);
TextView updateText;

for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
    updateText = (TextView) container.getChildAt(i);
    // Do something to `updateText`
}
```

**Update:** That's the general idiom for this type of thing.  I just looked more closely at your code, and if I understand what you're trying to do in this case, you want to iterate over the table rows and do something to the specific `TextArea` of each row.  If so, then instead of `courtText1`, `courtText2`, etc., you should get rid of the number.  Have one `courtText`, one `upateText`, and one `timeText` per row.  Then do something like this:

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.give_it_an_id);
TextView courtText;

// For each row
for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
    // Get the one `courtText` in this row
    courtText = table.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.courtText);
    if (courtText != null) {
        // Do something to `courtText`
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this helped a lot! This allows me to use the value of one of the text elements in each row to query a database. But, now I'm having trouble using the retrieved object from the query to update the other text elements. Posted a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060499/how-to-use-data-provided-in-a-getcallback-outside-of-the-getcallback

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how many and you know the ids... you can easily do something like,

```
for (int id : new int[] {R.id.courtText1, R.id.timeText1, R.id.updateText1, R.id.courtText2, R.id.timeText2, R.id.updateText2}) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewbyId(id);
    // do something with the view
}
```

But, perhaps if you are having a bunch of repeated structures, then maybe a custom `Adapter` and a `GridView` would suit it better.