# How to use data provided in a getCallback outside of the getCallback

Tags: android

So I'm using Parse for now to run the backend of my app. When you query your Parse database, data is returned in a seemingly weird way (to me, but I'm new to this) -

```
            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
              if (object == null) {
              } else {
              }
            }
          });
```

And the data from the query is available for example within the Else statement. I can do                     Date time = object.getCreatedAt(); to get the time the retrieved object was created at.

But, the problem comes about because I want to use that data to update the text of a textView within my app. I feel like the data is "stuck" inside the callBack (which I realize is probably not true. The way I'm trying to do it I get an error: "Cannot refer to a non-final variable updateText inside an inner class defined in a different method". The error is on updateText, timeText, table, and i. Here is the relevant code snippet that is failing -

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    TextView courtText;
    TextView updateText;
    TextView timeText;
    // For each row
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
        // Get the one `courtText` in this row
        courtText = (TextView) table.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.courtText);

        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Updates");
        query.whereEqualTo("court",courtText);
        query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
              if (object == null) {
                Log.d("update", "The getFirst request failed.");
              } else {
                Log.d("update", "Retrieved the object.");

                String update = object.getString("update");
                Date time = object.getCreatedAt();

                updateText = (TextView) table.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.updateText);
                timeText = (TextView) table.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.timeText);

                updateText.setText(update);
                java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
                timeText.setText(dateFormat.format(time));
              }
            }
          });

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to test it right now, but something like this should work:

```
final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
TextView courtText;

for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
    courtText = (TextView) table.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.courtText);
    final TextView updateText = (TextView) table.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.updateText);
    final TextView timeText = (TextView) table.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.timeText);

    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Updates");
    query.whereEqualTo("court",courtText);
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (object == null) {
                Log.d("update", "The getFirst request failed.");
            } else {
                Log.d("update", "Retrieved the object.");

                String update = object.getString("update");
                Date time = object.getCreatedAt();

                updateText.setText(update);
                java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
                timeText.setText(dateFormat.format(time));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This way the only two variables from outside the inner class that need to be accessed from inside it (`updateText` and `timeText`) are declared `final`, so everything should work.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, as the loop incrementor 'i' isn't available inside the else statement. I've been trying to select the row based on the text (which will match one of the values in the returned object) to no avail. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @user1434163 Sorry, that was an oversight on my part.  I've updated my answer so it should work now.

Comment: Awesome... man, I tried a lot of different things, but for some reason this wasn't one of them. You are a life saver, my project can now go forward! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to resolve this. One, as Darshan said, is to make table final. This will allow you to access it from inside the GetCallback object (an inner class) without error. The second way is to refer back to the parent object - if this code is, for example, in an Activity subclass called `DisplayTableActivity`, you could put a method into it `UpdateTable(String updateText, String timeText)`, and instead of accessing the table directly in the GetCallback object, have the following line:

```
DisplayTableActivity.this.UpdateTable(updateText, timeText);
```

That way, you can get the table's views inside that function (which belongs to the Activity) without any problems.

Comment: The problem is, I need to let the UpdateTable() function (to use your example), which row to update based on the incrementor in the for loop. I envision it as during each loop, it would query for a row and update that row with the returned data. Maybe I'm thinking about it wrong?